# Can mutation observer listen for changes in "data-" attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers

So the problem is that I have an html element which has an object in a "data-" attribute (set via jQuery ofc) and I want to listen to changes in that attribute.

I have already tried a lot of things, like setting almost all possible combination values in the [MutationObserverInit object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit), but none of this help.

Does anybody know if it is possible?

```js
$('#some-id').click( function() {
  //$('#some-id').attr('title', 'some-title'); //this works
  $('#some-id').data('foo', 'bar1'); //this don't
});

var functionCallBack = function(mutations) {
  alert('something changed')
}

// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById("some-id");

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(functionCallBack);

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { subtree: true, childList: true , attributes: true};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

$('#some-id').data('foo', 'bar');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-id">HEY</div>
```

Comment: Please show what exactly you have tried. Of course it’s possible to listen for `data-` attribute changes with `MutationObserver`.

Comment: *"set via jQuery"* ... if it's set using `data()` method it won't be an attribute. Please show all relevant code if you want help

Comment: @Xufox I added a jsfiddle.

Comment: @charlietfl I added a jsfiddle. How can I resolve it then? What's the best option?

Comment: Use this: https://jsfiddle.net/u5Lcfayf/2/ when using data() method, data you've set are stored in one random-named (?) jQuery object, which is not reachable to MutationObserver (it seems).

Answer (score 3):

**New Answer (Based on [Oriol's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41539655/1347953)):**

I think Oriol provided a better approach but it could be optimized further.

```js
var object = {
  'key': 'value'
};

$('.addObj').click(function() {
  $('#some-id').observeData('foo', object, function() {
    console.log("Object Added");
  });
});

$('.removeObj').click(function() {
  $('#some-id').observeData('foo', null, function() {
    console.log("Object removed");
  });
});


jQuery.fn.observeData = function(name, object, callback) {
  // Get elemenet
  var element = $(this[0]);

  // Add data
  element.data(name, object);

  // Call the callback function
  callback();

  // Return this for a chainable function
  return this;
};
```

```css
span {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
}
span:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#some-id {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-id">HEY</div>

<span class='addObj'>Add Object</span>
<span class='removeObj'>Remove Object</span>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t012rb9j/1/

**Old Answer:**

As you stated in your code:

```
$('#some-id').click(function() {

 // $('#some-id').attr('title', 'some-title'); //this works
 $('#some-id').data('foo', 'bar1'); //this don't
});
```

.attr() works while .data() is not working. The reason is that .attr() **adds** an an attribute value to your HTML tag while data **stores** this data in memory.

From jQuery documentation:

> **[.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)**: Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element and/or return the value that was set.
>
> **[.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)**: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every
>   matched element.

One way to detect data changes (if you want to store an object) is to combine both functions.

```js
var object = {
  'key': 'value'
};

$('.addObj').click(function() {
  $('#some-id').data('foo', object).attr("data-attached", "true");
});

$('.removeObj').click(function() {
  $('#some-id').data('foo', null).attr("data-attached", "false");
});


var functionCallBack = function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (jQuery(mutation.target).attr("data-attached") == "true") {
      // Your code here
      console.log("Object Added");
    } else {
      console.log("Object removed");
    }
  });
}

// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById("some-id");

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(functionCallBack);

// configuration of the observer:
var config = {
  subtree: true,
  childList: true,
  attributes: true
};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```css
.addObj, .removeObj {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.addObj:hover, .removeObj:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#some-id {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-id">HEY</div>

<span class='addObj'>Add Object</span>
<span class='removeObj'>Remove Object</span>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xkb6jv4/

Comment: `data` modifies the DOM property, while `attr` modifies the HTML attribute. Those are the correct terms. Everything is stored in memory somehow.

Comment: `attr()` is both getter and setter

Comment: @Xufox, so is it possible to do this using jQuery data()?

Comment: @sinisake I’m not sure how this would follow from my comment. It’s possible with `attr`.

Comment: @Xufox, well, yes attr() is solution, but: "MutationObserver provides developers a way to react to changes in a DOM." And you said: "data modifies DOM property", why Mutation Observer can't reach it?

Comment: I can use .attr() if the value is a string (which is in the jsfiddle), but in my real case it is an object. I can use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, but I prefer an elegant solution...

Comment: @Xufox, I don't think `data` adds anything to the DOM, not even to its properties. It stores a reference of the DOM object, along with the saved data, but I don't think it attaches to the DOM object at all. It's only internal.

Comment: @KalimahApps I don't get your solution. Can you please make it in the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect new data set with jQuery's `data`, you can always hijack it.

```js
var functionCallBack;
var $data = jQuery.fn.data;
jQuery.fn.data = function(key, value) {
  var ret = $data.apply(this, arguments);
  if(functionCallBack && this[0] && value !== undefined) {
    functionCallBack(this, key, value);
  }
  return ret;
};

$('#some-id').click( function() {
  $(this).data('foo', 'bar1');
}).data('foo', 'bar');
functionCallBack = function(elements, key, value) {
  console.log('something changed')
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-id">HEY</div>
```