# Detecting when data attribute changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a microsite where I'd like to swap out content depending upon if a change to the parent containers data attribute occurs.

```
<div id="app" data-page="1"></div>
```

Next I have a button that gets the data attribute and then increments on click.

```
var page = +$('#app').attr('data-page');
$('#button__page-change').on('click', function() {
  page = page + 1;
  $('#app').attr('data-page', page);
});
```

The next step now is to detect whenever that page is changed. I was thinking along the lines of a switch statement.

```
switch (page) {
  case 2:
    console.log('page: ', page);
  break;
  case 3:
    console.log('page: ', page);
  break;
  default: 
   console.log('switch statement does not appear to be working');
  break;
}
```

The switch seems to not  be meeting any of the conditions and therefore going to the default case. But with that said, I was trying to perhaps put it inside a on change function. But I didn't seem to have any luck with that as nothing was logged to the console.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're probably approaching the problem in the opposite way: instead of trying to detect when the data attribute has changed, you can try to either (1) perform the logic within the click handler itself, or (2) emit a custom event that is being listened to. In that way, you can subscribe to changes in the data attribute, no? If you still want to go with your approach, then you might want to consider [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can mutation observer listen for changes in "data-" attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538686/can-mutation-observer-listen-for-changes-in-data-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Well, if you can use only `$.data()` function, you can intercept its executions as follow:**

- Get the current jQuery's `data` function.
- Execute the native jQuery's `data` function.
- Get the result.
- Execute your logic for page detection.
- Return the result from the jQuery's `data` function.

```js
var page = +$('#app').data('page');

var dataFn = $.fn.data;
$.fn.data = function(value, data) {
  var result = dataFn.call(this, value);
  executePageDetection(value, data);
  return result;
};

$('#button__page-change').on('click', function() {
  page = page + 1;
  $('#app').data('page', page);
});

var executePageDetection = function() {
  switch (page) {
    case 2:
      console.log('page: ', page);
      break;
    case 3:
      console.log('page: ', page);
      break;
    default:
      console.log('switch statement does not appear to be working');
      break;
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" data-page="1"></div>

<button id='button__page-change'>Click me</button>
```

Comment: So we posted answers around the same time(thank you by the way). Would there be any benefit to approaching it this way as opposed to the result I came to which seems to do exactly what I need?

Comment: @thelgloriouspast your approach is good if it meets all that you need.  My answer is regarding to your question's title: *Detecting when data attribute changes* :-)

Comment: @Ele haha fair enough. Thank you for the assistance, plus the explanation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So as I posted this I actually came to the idea of what if I put the switch statement in an on click function instead. Because the navigational flow will always be clicking buttons, why not stick the switch statement in there. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear 'em. But this seemed to work for me.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
switch (page) {
  case 1: 
    console.log('page: ', page);
  break;    
  case 2:
    console.log('page: ', page);
  break;
  case 3:
    console.log('page: ', page);
  break;
  default: 
   console.log('switch statement does not appear to be working');
  break;
}   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be doing what you are wanting. I am using get and set attribute to find the data page and then add to it.

```js
function check(){
var dt = document.getElementById("app");
var att = dt.getAttribute("data-page")
var page = parseInt(att)  + 1 
dt.setAttribute("data-page", page);

switch (page) {
  case 2:
    console.log('page: ', page);
  break;
  case 3:
    console.log('page: ', page);
  break;
  default: 
   console.log('switch statement does not appear to be working' + page);
  break;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" data-page="1"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="check();" value="go">
```